# How to measure the resource use of a system call?

Tags: linux, c, resources

I've written two system calls, and want to compare the memory used up by each one. How could I go about doing this? I've tried `getrusage`, but almost all of the fields are 0.  Thank you!

Comment: please add the code or commands you have used then it will be easier to answer your question